# Erro em linha de PostService com springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Ola, estou fazendo um CRUD com springboot porem estou tendo um erro em apenas uma unica linha, e gostaria de saber como resolver, pois comecei a estudar a ferramenta recentemente, obrigado!!

ERRO: Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.matera.blog.model.Post'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo os codigos:

BlogApplication.java (Main class):

```
package com.matera.blog.blog;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BlogApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BlogApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

PostController.java (Controller):

```
package com.matera.blog.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.matera.blog.model.Post;
import com.matera.blog.service.PostService;

@Controller
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService service;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView findAll() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/post");
        mv.addObject("posts", service.findAll());

        return mv;
    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public ModelAndView add(Post post) {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/postAdd");
        mv.addObject("post", post);

        return mv;
    }

    @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

        return add(service.findOne(id));
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

        service.delete(id);

        return findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ModelAndView save(@Valid Post post, BindingResult result) {

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return add(post);
        }

        service.save(post);

        return findAll();
    }

}
```

Post.java (Model):

```
package com.matera.blog.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity(name = "tbl_post")
public class Post implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "post_seq", sequenceName = "post_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "post_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    @NotBlank(message = "Autor é uma informação obrigatória.")
    private String autor;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 150)
    @NotBlank(message = "Título é uma informação obrigatória.")
    private String titulo;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 2000)
    @NotBlank(message = "Texto é uma informação obrigatória.")
    private String texto;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @NotNull(message = "Data é uma informação obrigatória.")
    private Date data;
}
```

PostRepository.java (Repository):

```
package com.matera.blog.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.matera.blog.model.Post;

@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
    void delete(Long id);
}
```

PostService.java (Service):

```
package com.matera.blog.service.;

import com.matera.blog.model.Post;
import com.matera.blog.repository.PostRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository repository;

    public List<Post> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public Post findOne(Long id) {
        return repository.findOne(id);
    }

    public Post save(Post post) {
        return repository.saveAndFlush(post);
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        repository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: dependendo da versão que você está utilizando acredito que você deveria substituir o findOne por findById

Comment: `findOne` foi [migrado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103020/5360385) para `findById`

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal!!